# Invalid_request error when requesting JWT User Token PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

Hello when trying to request my token it gives me the following error:

```
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:15:"invalid_request";}
```

The code I am using in PHP is the following:

```
  $config = new Configuration();
    $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);

    $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(static::$BASEPATH);
    $privateKey = file_get_contents(env('RUTA_ESIGN_KEY'), true);

    $jwt_scope = "signature impersonation"; 

    $response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
       static::$INTEGRACION_KEY,
       static::$USER_ID,
       $privateKey,
       $jwt_scope
    );

    dd($response);
```

I am using PHP with Laravel. Thanks

Comment: Value for these are good?
$INTEGRACION_KEY,
       static::$USER_ID,
       $privateKey,
       $jwt_scope

Comment: Especially $privateKey, what is that? is that a string? what does it look like? what format?

Comment: If all are correct, the Integration Key is the one I get from the panel, the user ID too, the private key is downloaded from the panel and it is a .key file and the jwt scope is declared in the code

Comment: does the private key start with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and ends with -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
??

Comment: Also, did you already obtain consent?

Answer (score 0):

The things to keep in mind to get JWT working are:

- Make sure you use the correct private key part of the RSA keypair exactly as it was given to you including end of lines etc.
- Double check the account Id, the user ID and that all the URLs point to the developer env (account-d.docusign.com)
- Make sure you got consent and that it includes the impersonation scope.

Those should all be double checked, but I also suggest you try our PHP
quickstart that configures it all for you automagically - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/